# Cannot understand "Single-file executables" feature in Net Core 3

Tags: .net-core

While learning how [Single-file executables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#single-file-executables) work in net core 3.1 I created net core 3.1 C# Console Application. If I compile the default project created by VS, I can see this set of files

[image]

In order to run this console app I have to distribute 3 files - ConsoleNetCore.exe/dll/runtimeconfig

Now I want to improve a distribution story and prefer to have just one single file to distribute so I don't have exe and dll but just an exe. As was outlined in the above link and modified my project file by adding these properties:

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
```

so the entire project file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Then I rebuilt the project and noticed an extra folder win10-x64 under netcoreapp3.1 with 226 files in there, mainly dlls including ConsoleNetCore.exe. I copied from there the exe and put it under c:\temp and ran it and got the error:

*The application to execute does not exist: 'c:\Temp\ConsoleNetCore.dll'*

I then copied there that dll and tried to run the exe again and this time got:

*A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'*

Obviously I failed producing Single-file executable, I expected literally a single exe file and nothing else so I could simply distribute that file, do I misinterpret this feature? How to make really single executable file which doesn't require any other files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that just rebuilding is not enough, I literally should Publish from within Visual Studio (or tools command line):

[image]